# Translating validation messages in runtime

Tags: breeze

My first post here so please be kind :)

We are developing a business app using breeze as the entity manager and the application needs to be translated into a few different languages. The user should be able to change the language without refreshing the page. Translating the breeze validation messages is quite simple, but they do not seem to have any effect when applying a while after the entity manager has been created. The code to illustrate the issue:

```
breeze.Validator.messageTemplates["maxLength"] = "This will be displayed";

var manager = new breeze.EntityManager();

breeze.Validator.messageTemplates["maxLength"] = "This will also be displayed, overriding the first one";

setTimeout(function(){
    breeze.Validator.messageTemplates["maxLength"] = "This will not be displayed however";
    console.log("is set now");
}, 10000); // or sometime in the future when user changes language
```

Is there a way to change the validation messages at any time in the application runtime?

Regards

Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question..

Apparently there is no effect in modifying the "breeze.Validator.messageTemplates" array after metadata has been loaded.

The way I "fixed" it was to set the message on each validator on each property on each entity found in the metadata.

```
function loadTranslatedValidationMessages() {
    var manager = datacontext.manager;
    var entityTypes = manager.metadataStore.getEntityTypes();

    angular.forEach(entityTypes, function(entityType){
        var properties = entityType.getProperties();
        angular.forEach(properties, function(property){
            var validators = property.validators;
            angular.forEach(validators, function(validator){
                if (we have translation for this validation){
                    var newMessage = call translation;
                    validator.context.messageTemplate = newMessage;
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```